# global variables in js, how to avoid them

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a `change()` function that uses a `setInterval()` to repeat an animation:

```
function change(){
    interval = setInterval(c,300);
    function c(){...}
    c()
}
```

The `c()` function does the work.
I also have a `stop()` function that stops all the animation and restore the initial situation:

```
function stop(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    ...
};
```

I've read that is better use the `var` keyword instead declaring a global variable. But I cannot get access from the `stop()` function to `interval` if I do so. Declaring `interval` outside the `change()` function also gives me a problem.

ok i'm trying the last solution proposed by Ben Aston. Here the code:

```
function Animator() {
  var id;

  return {
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
  };

  function start() {
    id = requestAnimationFrame(go);
  }

  function stop() {
    clearAnimationFrame(id);
  }

  function go() {
    // increment the animation
        for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
                var num = randNum(0,img.length-1)
                var btn = img[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes[1]
                    img[i].setAttribute("src",img_path[num].path);
                        $(btn).css({"background-color":img_path[num].color,"border":"4px solid"+img_path[num].color});
                        $(img[i]).animate({width: "-=80px", height: "-=80px"},'slow');
                        $(img[i]).animate({width: "+=80px", height: "+=80px"},'slow')}

            id = requestAnimationFrame(go)
                }


 }
```

basically when the user press a button, the images start to change their width and height and their color.
 this is the rest:

```
var animator = new Animator();

function stop(){ //fn related to the stop button
    animator.stop()};


function change(){ //fn related to the start button
    animator.start()}
```

I dont know how to use requestAnimationFrame properly, i'm studying it right now. but when i press the start button the images change just one time and then they stopped.
In the previous code i had a for loop that did the work:

```
function change(){

    interval = setInterval(c,300);
    function c(){
                for (var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
                    var num = randNum(0,img.length-1)
                    var btn = img[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes[1]
                        img[i].setAttribute("src",img_path[num].path);
                            $(btn).css({"background-color":img_path[num].color,"border":"4px solid"+img_path[num].color});
                            $(img[i]).animate({width: "-=80px", height: "-=80px"},'slow');
                            $(img[i]).animate({width: "+=80px", height: "+=80px"},'slow')}}
    c()}
```

I admit that i dont have quite clear how to implement the go func?
thanks

edit: now it works (i was working with another file :)) but i have problem with the stop button

Comment: I'm going to try and address the root issue. You should be programming your animation as a CSS class that gets toggled once, not a JavaScript function that gets called at a specified interval.

Comment: Since functions are objects, you can also use `change.interval` if you want

Comment: Yes, you will need to declare it outside of `change`, but a) you indeed should *declare* it explicitly and b) it doesn't necessarily need to reside in the global scope

Answer (score 1):

You can use Closure as well, read the documentation here :
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
With Closure you can define private and public function.

Answer (score 1):

In raw JavaScript you could do the following:

Using ES5:

```
function Animator() {
  var id;

  return {
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
  };

  function start() {
    id = requestAnimationFrame(go);
  }

  function stop() {
    clearAnimationFrame(id);
  }

  function go() {

    // increment the animation...

    if(shouldContinue()) { // you define `shouldContinue`
      id = requestAnimationFrame(go);
    }    
  }
}

var animator = new Animator();
animator.start();
// ...
animator.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

hi using closures and with set interval things works properly:

```
var Button_Obj = function(){
  var intervalID;

  function start(){
    return intervalID = setInterval(change,300) //change is the function that do the animation with a loop, i keep it private
  };
function stop(){
    clearInterval(intervalID)
    };
return {start : start, stop : stop}
```

now in the global space i have only:

```
var btn_trigger = new Button_Obj();
```

and in the button tag i put:

```
<button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button" id="change-order"  onclick="btn_trigger.start()"  type="button">Start Moving</button>
```

now the global space is more clean, this implmentation works, with RequestAnimationFrame i have some problem, but i will try with it as well later